# Cannot select data from DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to get the job information (Oracle 11g) by using the following query:

```
SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS
WHERE JOB_NAME = 'CHECK_DATES_ON_LOGIN';
```

but it says "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".
I am able to describe the table but unable to select from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need DBA privileges to be able to select from that view. If you want to see the jobs the *current* user owns, use `user_scheduler_jobs`

```
SELECT job_name, state 
FROM user_scheduler_jobs
WHERE job_name = 'CHECK_DATES_ON_LOGIN';
```